# How Mysql stores Data which are entered simultaneously by number of users?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications

Currently I am developing a Web Application, **A Citizen Registration System.** Many Government Representatives (My Web App Admins) are going to number of towns and register citizens. This is done by collaboration with over **50,000+ representatives** for a months. All data they have gathered are entered to the system on-the-fly. It means that there will be **over 30,000+ representatives who enter data simultaneously to the system.** Think my system's database has only one table (citizens) and all I need to know is,

1. How MySQL handle such simultaneous inputs?
2. How Unique Ids (citizen_id) would be created?
3. Are there any **MySQL or PHP strategy OR Coding Practice** should I consider or follow?
4. What happens if Two users entered data **Exactly the same time**?
5. **Will MySQL with-stand such massive simultaneous inputs?**

Thank you in advance..!

Comment: hmmm .... how likely is it that a government willing to expense 50000 representatives on a mission would contract a person that needed to ask these 5 questions in crafting a mission critical system ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - Just imagine..!!! Not a real world scenario... :p

Comment: I imagine it'll be fine. It can't be any worse than the IT projects my government presently commissions